# Logparser query for netapp logs

Tags: powershell, logparser

I'm trying to write a log parser for NetApp logs using PowerShell.

The script goes as below:

```
$logparser = "c:\program files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe"
$query = “SELECT TimeCreated  SystemTime,EventID,EventName,Computer,ComputerUUID,EventCategoryName,SourceName,EventData Data INTO D:\Temp\audit_EUPNPSVM-SCM-FC-NAS_D2018-01-09-T10-32-49_0000000000.csv FROM D:\Temp\audit_EUPNPSVM-SCM-FC-NAS_D2018-01-09-T10-32-49_0000000000.evtx" WHERE EventData(Data Name= 'ObjectName')
& $logparser -i:evt -o:csv $query
$ps.WaitForExit()
$ps.ExitCode;
```

I get error:

```
PS C:\> C:\script\test2.ps1
At C:\script\test2.ps1:2 char:279
+ ... 00000000.evtx" WHERE EventData(Data Name= 'ObjectName')
+                    ~~~~~
Unexpected token 'WHERE' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: You look to have an extra quotation mark in there. You close the quoted string after the filename `...evtx"`

Comment: I have added only 1 quotation. Let me know if you identify any other issue.

Comment: The code, as posted, has syntax errors due to quoting. You need to fix them.

Comment: I did remove the where condition itself. Let me give you the background.

Comment: WE have a application running on NAS share of netapp server. The logs are collected on the NAS share itself. The task with me is to dump it locally and convert the cifs file to a CSV file, so that we can have a SIEM connector pick the logs. The issue I have here is that the log parser is not able to identify many of the fields.

Comment: I initially scripted as:
$logparser = "c:\program files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\logparser.exe"
$query = "SELECT * INTO D:\Temp\audit_EUPNPSVM-SCM-FC-NAS_D2018-01-09-T10-32-49_0000000000.csv FROM D:\Temp\audit_EUPNPSVM-SCM-FC-NAS_D2018-01-09-T10-32-49_0000000000.evtx"
& $logparser -i:evt -o:csv $query
$ps.WaitForExit()
$ps.ExitCode;
I did get the CSV file as well but with fields 
The name for category 65535 in Source "NetApp-Security-Auditing" cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer

Comment: I would like to pick the custom fields in the logs, does log parser work this way and how do i define it?

Comment: LogParser picks all the fields it can find in the CSV file. If the CSV file has a header, the fields will be named according to the header. There are plenty of options to fine-tune this behavior, they are all fully explained in the documentation.